Package Controll not working in Sublime Text 4
I am trying to use the Package Control: InstallPackage command to download PackageResourceViewer. However, when I use the Package Control: InstallPackage command, nothing happens, no package menu pops up. A similar thing happens to similar package control commands.
I checked the settings to see if Package control was listed as an ignored package which it was so I removed the code and saved the file but Package control still doesn't work. Also, when I went to Preferences - Package settings - Package control - Settings, The settings code said
{
"in_process_packages":
[
"PackageResourceViewer
],
}
I dont know what this means. Does this mean I already downloaded it? I dont know how that could be the case.
How can I solve this and get PackageResourceViewer?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
